# Can ∅, as being an element of a set, be handled as any other element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that by definition, ∅ is a subset of every set but I have a doubt about it appearing as an explicit element of a set. In a union between sets and the finding of the Power of that set, can it be handled as any other normal element?

Eg.:
Set A={∅, {∅}}, P(A) = {∅, {∅}, {{∅}} {∅,{∅}}};

{∅}U{{∅}}={∅,{∅}}?

Edit: the question was edited to make it a little more usefull for other people, if any other editions are necessary, feel free.

Comment: $A\cup \emptyset = A$ for all $A$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: But there's no $A\cup\varnothing$ anywhere in the question.

Comment: I just saw "nullology" and used it as a tag for its description is "Study of null set theory" - I found it to be possibly a good bet. :P

Comment: @HenningMakholm There was, back then, in the title "[t]he union of ∅ with any other element or Set"

Comment: I edited it, changing from element to subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you speak about "contained in" there's a risk of confusion, because this language doesn't distinguish reliably between "is an element of" and "is a subset of", which are entirely different concepts. In many cases, the types of things can help disambiguate -- if you see "$A$ is contained in $B$" and you already know $A$ and $B$ as sets of real numbers, you can conclude that "subset" is what was meant. Conversely if you know $A$ as a single number and $B$ as a set of number, it's a safe bet that "element" was meant. But when you're talking about pure untyped set theory, "contained in" is ambiguous language and should be avoided.

The empty set *as a member of* another set works just like any other mathematical object.

So $\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\{\varnothing\}\} = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, simply because $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are all the elements of $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

However, you're missing an element of $\mathcal P(A)$, it should be
$$\mathcal P(\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}) = \{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}, \{\{\varnothing\}\}, \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\} $$

Comment: So ∅ is a element of A such that when talking about its partitions it has to become a subset {∅}, right? Even with ∅ as element I have to work with 2^n elements for the Set of partitions?

Comment: @TiagoSirious: I'm not sure what you mean by "has to become a subset". I suspect your meaning is wrong and confused. If you're looking for partitions of your $A$, handle the $\varnothing$ exactly as you would any other element -- it's immaterial whether it says $\varnothing$ or $42$.

Comment: @TiagoSirious: Note also that the notation $\mathcal P(A)$ usually stands for the _power set_ of $A$ -- that is, the set of all $A$'s subsets -- which is something different from "partitions" of $A$.

Comment: Okay Henning. I'm sorry about my confusion of therms. I do not speak english natively nor am studying the subject in english, so I'm sort of translating it in order to try to get the information I need. You just offered me it. In the end, I wanted to know if ∅ should be handled as any other element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not true, that $\emptyset$ is contained in every set. Counterexample is $A=\{1\}$, then $\emptyset \notin A$, even is we write $1$ into the [form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Constructions_based_on_set_theory) $1=\{ \emptyset \}.$

Your example is also wrong. Let $A=\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$, then $\wp\left(A\right) = \left\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}, \{ \emptyset,  \{ \emptyset \} \} \right\} $. In general if $A$ is a finite set and the cardinality of $A$ is $n$, then $\wp(A)$ has $2^n$ elements. And your example has $3$ elements not $4$ so even because of that it couldn't be correct.

And to answer you question. Yes,
$$\{ \emptyset \} \cup \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} = \left\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \right\}.$$

Comment: As in Henning, I could get that ∅ can be treated as any other element. Thanks!

Comment: @TiagoSirious You're welcome.